# Disable Auto Login After Woo-commerce Checkout is Completed

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, checkout, auto

We have setup a Woocommerce website to create new accounts on user checkout.

When the user completes this process they are redirected to the order confirmation page and logged in to the website.

Is there a filter available that disables Woocommerce from logging in new customers once they complete the Checkout process?

Answer (score 0):

User gets registered with checkout process

You can use this to prevent user login after a new registration.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_auth_new_customer', '__return_false' );
```